Split brain requirement for SQL always on availability group
I have 2 nodes on the Primary site and 1 node on the DR site. I want to add another node on the DR site so both Primary and DR site have HA. My file share witness exists on 2nd node of Primary site.
Please confirm if any risk of split brain in case of SQL Always On with file share witness?
Is there any requirement of 5th Node for split brain for odd number of nodes where we already have SQL Always On with file share witness?

I am pretty sure your file share witness should NOT be on one of the nodes, because if that node goes down you lose 2 quorum votes in one hit
That said I don't think there is a problem with having an equal number of quorum votes as long as you have dynamic quorum configured
you can check this with Powershell :-
Get-Cluster|fl name, dynamicQuorum, WitnessDynamicWeight
